# Zend_Gdata_YouTube detect removed video

Tags: zend-framework, zend-gdata

I have the following code which is used to load video information from YouTube onto my site:

```
try {
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
    $videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry($video_path);
    $duration = $videoEntry->getVideoDuration();
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e) {
    //do something with the error
}
```

The problem I have is that I've detected, so far, 2 scenarios where the catch block will be executed - if the video has been removed, or if there is some sort of communication error.

If the video has been removed, I want to remove it from my local listing. How can I tell which error I'm getting - I've been looking for a description of the error codes, and can't find this, though I'm sure other people have run into this issue before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the video ID you are looking for was deleted or never existed, the HTTP status code for the request will be 400 and the body of the response is `Invalid id`.  You can get the underlying response object to determine if the request was invalid, or if the request failed completely.

```
try {
    $yt         = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
    $videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry($video_path);
    $duration   = $videoEntry->getVideoDuration();
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e) {
    $response = $e->getResponse();

    if ($response !== null) {
        if ($response->getStatus() == 400 && $response->getBody() == 'Invalid id') {
            // the video requested does not exist or was deleted
        } else {
            // some other error
        }
    }
}
```